# ¿Cómo puedo hacer que el programa termine cuando el valor de (X) sea 0?

Tags: c

El programa ya es funcional, pero al hacer una condicion para que el programa termine cuando x valga cero, me da error ya que no me deja terminar el programa, me podrían ayudar o aconsejar como puedo hacer que mi programa termine cuando x sea igual a cero.

```
/*Elabora un programa en lenguaje C para obtener el resultado de elevar (X) a la potencia (n) 
    mediante una función desarrollada por ti. El programa debe solicitar los valores de (X) y de (n) 
    y mostrar el resultado. El programa debe terminar cuando el valor de (X) sea 0.*/

#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int x; //Número a elevar
    int n; //Potencia a la que se elevara
    int r=1; //Resultado
    int i=1; //contador

    cout<<"Ingrese el numero que desea elevar"<<endl;
    cin>>x;

    cout<<"Ingrese la potencia a la que quiere elevarlo"<<endl;
    cin>>n; 

    while(i<=n)
    {
        r = r*x;
        i++;
    }

    system("pause");
} //Fin Programa
```

Comment: No veo esa condición que comentas en tu código... no se trata de que nos pongas un código que piensas que funciona...sino el ejemplo que no te funciona para que podamos ayudarte. Es decir ¿Cómo estás intentando evaluar X=0?

Comment: Cuando el usuario ponga 0 en el primer apartado el cual es "Ingrese el número a elevar", necesito que el programa termine automáticamente, pero si pone otro número que no sea 0 el programa debe continuar sin salir, disculpa, no lo hice muy entendible.

Comment: Eso lo he entendido al leer la pregunta... sin embardo dices que has intentado añadir la condición sin éxito... yo no veo esa condición por ningún lado

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Una manera no tan ortodoxa de lograr lo que pides es, justo después de leer al numero a elevar, comprobar si es cero, si es el caso, llamas a la función exit:

```
/*Elabora un programa en lenguaje C para obtener el resultado de elevar (X) a la potencia (n)
    mediante una función desarrollada por ti. El programa debe solicitar los valores de (X) y de (n)
    y mostrar el resultado. El programa debe terminar cuando el valor de (X) sea 0.*/

#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int x; //Número a elevar
    int n; //Potencia a la que se elevara
    int r=1; //Resultado
    int i=1; //contador

    cout<<"Ingrese el numero que desea elevar"<<endl;
    cin>>x;

    if(x==0){     //Aqui compruebas si es cero el numero a elevar
        exit(0);  //Con esta función sales del programa, el 0 es código de salida cuando el programa termina, podrías bien cambiarlo por -1 para especificar que hubo un "error"
    }

    cout<<"Ingrese la potencia a la que quiere elevarlo"<<endl;
    cin>>n;

    while(i<=n)
    {
        r = r*x;
        i++;
    }

    system("pause");
} //Fin Programa
```

Si lo ejecutas y pones cero:

```
Ingrese el numero que desea elevar
0

Process returned 0 (0x0)   execution time : 8.902 s
Press any key to continue.
```

Answer (score 0):

La idea es que nos muestres que parte del código no funciona, nos dices que hay un condicional que no te funciona, pero si vemos el código que nos compartiste no hay un condicional como tu indicas sin embargo, la solución a esto es poner un condicional que nos compare si la x es igual cero y si lo es que retorne 0,  entonces el código sería

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int x; //Número a elevar
    int n; //Potencia a la que se elevara
    int r=1; //Resultado
    int i=1; //contador

    cout<<"Ingrese el numero que desea elevar"<<endl;
    cin>>x;

    cout<<"Ingrese la potencia a la que quiere elevarlo"<<endl;
    cin>>n; 

   if( x == 0)
       {
         cout<<"El resultado es : 0"<<endl;
         return 0;
        }

    while(i<=n)
    {
        r = r*x;
        i++;
    }

    system("pause");
} //Fin Programa
```

Comment: En este caso `x` es la base, no el exponente, por lo que no daría 1.